# Share Image from collectionView to Facebook - Crash of optional value

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, uicollectionview, share

I got a crash if I want to share a img from a collectionView to Facebook like this. I use Facebook SDK for swift via CocoaPods.
If I understand it right, then is the URL from my image NIL. But on the other hand, if i click on "myImage" the img is loaded. Hmmm what is wrong?

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import FacebookLogin
import FacebookShare



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        cell?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
        cell?.layer.borderWidth = 2

        let imageCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! imageCellCollectionViewCell
        //        let imageCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! imageCellCollectionViewCell
        guard let myImage = imageCell.imageToShare.image else {
            print("leer")
            return
        }

        let photo = Photo(image: myImage, userGenerated: true)
        let content = PhotoShareContent(photos: [photo])
        do {
            try ShareDialog.show(from: myController, content: content)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your myImage is not nil, its myController or content variable. Try to print it you will see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check your `myController` object. Maybe it is nil:

```
if let vc = myController {
        do {
            try ShareDialog.show(from: vc, content: content)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
}
```

If collection View delegate method are implemented in your MyViewController then you can directly use `Self` Like this way:

```
do {
   try ShareDialog.show(from: Self, content: content)
 } catch {
   print(error)
 }
```

Comment: Oh wow - thats true.... but why is it nil? I do it like this: var myController  : MyViewController!

Comment: @webschnecke: can you show me your code for myController?

Comment: The `!` in `var myController : MyViewController!` means that you're guaranteeing `myController` will have a value by the time this object is done initializing. It doesn't actually initialize the value for you - that's on you. If you don't, it will be nil.

Comment: @JaredH: Yes exactly

Comment: @JogendarChoudhary 
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

Comment: @webschnecke: You need to pass "Self"

Comment: @webschnecke: I have updated my answer, Please check

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer ;-) DAMN... self and not vc.
Can anybody explain it to me? What is the difference?

```
do {
            try ShareDialog.show(from: self, content: content)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
```